# Handling an undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I render a partial in one view:

```
<%= render 'video', :video => @video, :video_id => 'video_show_id' %>
```

and have this code in the partial:

```
<% if video_id %>
  <%= link_to "video", video.video_url, :class => "oembed", :id => video_id %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "video", video.video_url, :class => "oembed" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this partial gets rendered in a number of places in my app, and in those other views I do not want to pass `:video_id` into the partial. Therefore my app throws an error that `video_id` is undefined. I could pass `:video_id => ""` into the partial in the other views, but since the partial is rendered in many places, that is kind of a pain. Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `defined?` and not that it really matters but it's actually an [operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#definedandorandnot).

```
<% if defined? video_id %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way to handle this is to create a helper that then manages the values of variables that need to fed to a partial.  Something like:

```
module VideoHelper 

  def show_video(video, options = {})
    options[:id] ||= ""
    render 'video', :video => video, :video_id => options[:id]
  end  

end
```

Now, instead of having to have that long render partial line in your view, you get to shorten it to a show_video call.

Also, I've found that in the long term, this allows for a lot more flexibility and I have to think a lot less about what variables the partial needs at this time and whether or not they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Change the check to `<% if defined? video_id %>`